# Image of compact set is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}^n}$
Consider a function $f:\R\rightarrow \R$, not necessarily continuous, and a compact subset $W$ of $\R$. Then, can we say that $f$ is bounded on $W$? If not, what is the counterexample?

Comment: Do you know what inversion is? It turns the inside of a ball into the outside of the ball and viceversa. It is not defined at $0$, since it would go to infinity. But if you allow discontinuous functions, then you can map $0 \mapsto 0$.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1/x^2$ when $x\neq0$ and $0$ at the origin, on $[-1,1]$. Or $f(x,\ldots)=(1/x^2,0,\ldots)$ on the punctured unit disc and $0$ at the origin.

Comment: @Hermis, I see no relation in your question between $W$ and $f$? Why $f$ needs to be bounded in $W$

Comment: @00GB Are you asking me with my question?

Comment: @Hermis14, yes I am

Comment: Just define $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ like $f(1/n)=n$ for all positive integers $n$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. $W=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i'm missing something but i think this is false. For example the function piecewise defined: Fix a point $p\neq 0$. $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $f(x) = \frac{p}{\|x\|}$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$ the unit closed ball $B = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\|\leq 1 \}$ is compact but near $0$ (and hence on $B$) $f$ is not bounded. Hope this helps.